# What are all the Flag Values from ARP Cache entries?

Tags: linux, networking, arp

When running "arp -a" on a linux machine, one of the values for each entry returned is "Flags." I've seen 0x0, 0x2, and 0x6 as possible values. All I have gathered so far is that 0x6 represents a permanent (ie: static and not dynamic) entry.

Is there a list somewhere of all of the possible flags for an arp cache entry? Can there ever be more than one flag for an entry?

Answer (score 2):

The answer can be found here (the question "Definition of Arp result flags?"): https://superuser.com/a/822089